# Onload function not working properly

Tags: javascript

Right now, the image is highlighted when the user clicks on an image . What I am trying to do is on onload, the first image will be highlighted until the user clicks on another image.  However, it is not working.  Am I doing this completely wrong?

```
      for (var i = 0; i < e.mediaList.length; i++) {
        var media = e.mediaList[i];
        if (media) {
          playlistHTML += '<div id="thumbwrap" >';
          if (i == 0){
          playlistHTML += '<a id="thumbwrap1" href="javascript:onPlaylistItemClick(\'' + media.id + '\');" onClick="javascript:highlightLink(this);" onload ="javascript:highlightLink(document.getElementById(this));">';}
          else{           
        playlistHTML += '<a id="thumbwrap1" href="javascript:onPlaylistItemClick(\'' + media.id + '\');" onClick="javascript:highlightLink(this);"  >';} #call function here


          playlistHTML += '<img width="106"  height="62" style="padding:2px;"  src="' + media.thumbnailUrl + '"/>';

          playlistHTML += '<div id="thumbwrap-title">' + media.title + '</div>';
          playlistHTML += '</a>';
          playlistHTML += '</div>';
        }
      }
```

Function for activating image highlight.

```
var highlightLink = function () {
        var active = null, colour = '#FF8C00';
        if (this.attachEvent) this.attachEvent('onunload', function () {
            active = null;
        });
        return function (element) {
            if ((active != element) && element.style) {
                if (active) active.style.backgroundColor = '';
                element.style.backgroundColor = colour;
                active = element;
            }
        };
    }();
```

Comment: where is the event being called? Generally speaking, you probably don't need this much code

Comment: Make code sample smaller. Get rid of CSS.

Comment: I am calling the code in the playlistHTML and the function is highlightLink.  Got rid of the extra code.  So hopefully that makes it easier to see the problem.

Comment: @DawnAbbot: Do you get any console errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onload` event is not supported by the `a` tag. You should attach the event to the `img` instead of the `a` tag.
Here is a list 
[List](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)  of tags that spport the `onload` event.